# Facebook 345 MB logo in the Brand Permissions Center

Tags: facebook

Hopefully this is localized but if not, there is a 345 MB file placed under the [Logos](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php) section where there should actually be a small PNG file instead.

Not sure what section of Facebook help forms would be suitable to report this "error".

Where should I report this?

Comment: This is a currently open bug, it should be resolved shortly

Comment: @Igy Thanks, though where would be the proper section to report things like this. I am traversing the help section to see if I can use one of the forms for next time.

Comment: Maybe this is one of the recent *revolutionary* changes in Facebook?

Comment: I actually came across this bug about 3 days ago via our own bug tracker, but in general the best place for bug reports like this is facebook.com/help - most of the FAQs have a way to get to some contact forms if the FAQ didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I am going to assume that the [Photo Bug Report form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=photos_bug) would be best place to report this (*if anything like this happened again*)